# Is there a way to find missing numbers in a sequence using in python from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

So I am trying to find things that are missing in a list of things. They are held in a pandas dataframe and they are in a column and the data looks something like this:

```
samples = ["ABC001", "ABC002", "ABC003", "ABC005", "ABC006", "DEF001", "DEF003"]
```

What ultimately I would like to find the missing ones ["ABC004", "DEF002"] and put those into a new list. The identifiers "ABC" or "DEF" may be more things than just that. I also have time data to work with to help with the process of finding missing things say that there is a 2 minute gap between when ABC004 and ABC006 was entered, when normally it should take 1 minute to enter.

Is there a smart way to do this. I have a sorted list, but I am having difficulty wrapping my head around how to go from there to get a list of the missing samples. Any advice would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` to split the alphabetic prefix from the numeric suffix. Turn the suffix into a numeric type, then `zfill` later to get it back into your format. Group by the prefix, reindex using the range of numeric values and store the missing ones in between in a list.

```
import pandas as pd

samples = ["ABC001", "ABC002", "ABC003", "ABC005", "ABC006", "DEF001", "DEF003"]
s = pd.Series(samples)
```

---

```
df = s.str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)')
df[1] = pd.to_numeric(df[1]) 

l = []
for prefix, gp in df.groupby(0):
    gp = gp.set_index(1).reindex(np.arange(gp[1].min(), gp[1].max()+1))
    gp = gp[gp[0].isnull()]
    l.extend([f'{prefix}{str(i).zfill(3)}' for i in gp.index])

print(l)
#['ABC004', 'DEF002']
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I needed, very clever. However, I get this error: gp = gp.set_index(1).reindex(np.arange(gp[1].min(), gp[1].max() + 1)) .... and cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. I am assuming that this method is inflexible with duplicates? How would I go about removing/compensating with this method?

Comment: @AndrewDisharoon oh yes. You can probably throw in a `df = df.drop_duplicates()` before the loop that way you won't run into any problems in the reindex step

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you want to find missing ones, I assume you have a list in mind that contains all values you want. You could make this list, for example:

```
ABC_samples = [f"ABC{x:03d}" for x in range(6)]
ABC_samples
>>> ['ABC000', 'ABC001', 'ABC002', 'ABC003', 'ABC004', 'ABC005']
```

Then you could query on the values that are not in both sets, e.g. the set of ABC_samples and the set of samples.

```
missing = set(samples) ^ set(ABC_samples)
missing
>>> {'ABC000', 'ABC0006', 'ABC004', 'DEF001', 'DEF003'}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know what to expect to be in these lists. They need to be made "on the fly". I just know that from the lowest to the highest number of a group, there shouldn't be any missing. But good thought!